# fatal error: Destructor cannot take arguments

Tags: php, android, mysql

i'am newbie in programming...
i try to call webservice from android. but i have fatal error there.

**1.this is android coding**

```
public class UserFunction {
    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String LoginURL="http://10.0.2.2/android/include/index.php";
    private static String RegisterURL="http://10.0.2.2/android/include/index.php";

    private static String login_tag="login";
    private static String register_tag="register";


    public UserFunction(){
        jsonParser=new JSONParser();
    }


    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        //building parameter
        List<NameValuePair> params= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(LoginURL, params);

        return json;
    }


    public JSONObject registerUser(String email, String name, String password){
        //building parameter
        List<NameValuePair> params= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        //getting JSONObject
        JSONObject json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(RegisterURL, params);

        return json;
    }


    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db= new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count=db.getRowCount();
        if(count>0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTable();
        return false;   
    }
}
```

**2.this is index.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['tag'])&& $_POST['tag'] !=''){
        //get tag
        $tag=$_POST['tag'];

        //include DB handler
        require_once ('DB_Functions.php');//ganti include
        $db=new DB_Functions();

        //response array
        $response=array ("tag"=> $tag, "Success"=>0, "error"=>0);

        //check 4 tag type
        if($tag='login'){
            //req type is check login
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            //check 4 user
            $user=$db->GetUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
            if($user !=false){
                /* user found
                * echo JSON with Success =1 */
                $response ["Success"]=1;
                $response["uid"]=$user["unique_id"];
                $response ["user"]["name"]=$user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"]=$user["email"];
                $response ["user"]["created_at"]=$user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"]=$user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            else{
                /* user not found
                * echo JSON with error =1 */
                $response ["Error"]=1;
                $response["error_msg"]="INCORRECT EMAIL OR PASSWORD!!!";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
        else if($tag=='register'){
            //req type is register new user
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            //check if user already existed
            if($db->IsUserExisted($email)){
                //user is already existed - error response
                $response["error"]=2;
                $response["error_msg"]="USER IS ALREADY EXISTS";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            else{
                //store user
                $user=$db->StoreUser($name, $email, $password);
                if($user){
                    //user stored successfull
                    $response ["Success"]=1;
                    $response["uid"]=$user["unique_id"];
                    $response ["user"]["name"]=$user["name"];
                    $response["user"]["email"]=$user["email"];
                    $response ["user"]["created_at"]=$user["created_at"];
                    $response["user"]["updated_at"]=$user["updated_at"];
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
                else{
                    //user failed to store
                    $response ["Error"]=1;
                    $response["error_msg"]="ERROR OCCURED IN REGISTRATION";
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "INVALID REQUEST";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "ACCESS DENIED";
    }
?>
```

**3. this is DB_Functions.php**

```
<?php
    class DB_Functions{
        private $db;
        /*constructor*/
        function __construct($db){
            require_once ('DB_Connect.php');//ganti include
            /*connecting DB*/
            $this->db= new DB_Connect();
            $this->db->connect();
        }
        /*destructor*/
        function __destruct($db){
        }

        /*
        *storing new user
        *returning user detail
        */

        public function StoreUser($name, $email, $password){
            $uuid= uniqid('',true);
            $hash= $this->hashSSHA($password);
            $encrypted_password= $hash["encrypted"]; //encripted password
            $salt=$hash["salt"];//salt
            $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO account_users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES ('$uuid','$name','$email','$encrypted_password','$salt',NOW())");
            /*check for succesfull store*/
            if($result){
                /*get user detail*/
                $uid= mysql_insert_id();
                $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account_users WHERE uid='$uid'");
                /*return user detail*/
                return mysql_fetch_array($result);
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        /*
        *get user by email & password
        */

        public function GetUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password){
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account_users WHERE email='$email'") or die (mysql_error());
            //check 4 result
            $no_of_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($no_of_rows>0){
                $result=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $salt=$result['salt'];
                $encrypted_password=$result['encrypted_password'];
                $hash=$this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
                //check pass equality
                if($encrypted_password==$hash){
                    //user auth are correct
                    return $result;
                }
            }
            else{
                //user not found
                return false;
            }
        }

        /*
        *check user existed or not
        */
        public function IsUserExisted($email){
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM account_users WHERE email='$email'");
            $no_of_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($no_of_rows>0){
                //user existed
                return true;
            }
            else{
                //user not existed
                return false;
            }
        }
        /*
        *encrypting pass
        *@param pass
        *return salt & encrpted pass
        */
        public function hashSHHA($password){
            $salt=sha1(rand());
            $salt=substr($salt, 0, 10);
            $encrypted= base64_encode(sha1($password.$salt, true).$salt);
            $hash=array("salt"=> $salt, "encrypted"=> $encrypted);
            return $hash();
        }
        /*
        *decrypting pass
        *@param salt, pass
        *return hash string
        */
        public function CheckHashSSHA($salt, $password){
            $hash=base64_encode(sha1($password.$salt, true).$salt);
            return $hash;
        }

    }
?>
```

**4. and the last this is the error when i run the android code**

```
07-18 02:07:59.393: D/dalvikvm(541): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3420 objects / 314064 bytes in 340ms
07-18 02:08:08.802: E/JSON(541): <br />n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Destructor DB_Functions::__destruct() cannot take arguments in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android\include\DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />n
07-18 02:08:08.802: E/JSON PARSER(541): Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-18 02:08:08.802: W/System.err(541): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 02:08:08.812: W/System.err(541):  at com.androidTA.androidclient.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:58)
07-18 02:08:08.812: W/System.err(541):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-18 02:08:08.812: W/System.err(541):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-18 02:08:08.812: W/System.err(541):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-18 02:08:08.812: W/System.err(541):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 02:08:08.812: W/System.err(541):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 02:08:08.812: W/System.err(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-18 02:08:08.822: W/System.err(541):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 02:08:08.858: W/System.err(541):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 02:08:08.858: W/System.err(541):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-18 02:08:08.858: W/System.err(541):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-18 02:08:08.862: W/System.err(541):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i've problem with the destruct function..., please anyone help me solve this..., a very big thanks for your solution,,, :)

Comment: You have error message with file and line, you posted the code of this file and mentioned error is there on this line. Have you tried to understand what does this error mean?

Comment: in my mind, that error mean that function destruct can't execute in DB_Functions.php, is that true?? correct me if that is false :)

Comment: Partially true. Before this could be executed, object should be created, and it can not be created because of wrong method declaration in class. Solution to this was provided below, but you have other error in `DB_Connect` class. Please try learning something about OOP in PHP before asking.

Comment: very big thanks to @dev-null-dweller finally i can fix that error with your suggestion to learn about OOP in php :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you spent some time an are able to fix simple errors for yourself :) Good luck with rest of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the *$db* parameter from your destructor. It should look like this.

```
/*destructor*/
function __destruct(){
}
```

If you need to access the database from the destructor, you can always use `$this->db` since you've already initialised that in the constructor.

In addition to that, you should really remove the `$db` parameter from the constructor as well. It's not being used, and you don't pass any arguments when you construct the `DB_functions` object in index.php.

Comment: but.. if i remove that parameter..., this error was happen 07-18 02:37:57.423: E/JSON(696): <br />n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Non-abstract method DB_Connect::__construct() must contain body in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android\include\DB_Connect.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />n  :(

Comment: @adhit_yogapratama Updated my answer - you should remove the $db parameter from the constructor as well.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all of the $db parameters from your constructor/destructor parameters. Like so:

```
    function __construct(){
        require_once ('DB_Connect.php');//ganti include
        /*connecting DB*/
        $this->db= new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }
```

You don't need the $db in the parameters list as you're referencing by $this->db, so it's not required.

```
    function __destruct(){
    }
```

You shouldn't have to pass any other parameters, as the object is cleared in its entirety

Comment: this is the error then 07-18 02:37:57.423: E/JSON(696): <br />n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Non-abstract method DB_Connect::__construct() must contain body in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android\include\DB_Connect.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />n
when i remove that parameter :(

Comment: Yes, because you have to remove the $db from the constructor also. Which will be fine, because you're referencing it by $this->db. As such, $db in the parameter list, isn't required.